# What does "whip-snap" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does *whip-snap* mean?

> Lured by its splashy fight scenes and **whip-snap** dialogue

Comment: I think it means "harsh". Just a guess by looking at the sentence.

Comment: @Apoorva : I'm sorry,but i just cannot understand what do you mean by describing a dialogue as "harsh"?

Comment: Harsh as in the dialogues are intense or rude.

Answer (score 5):

It is a metaphor for the snapping or cracking of a whip. Imagine a whip act at a circus.

*Snappy* is a common adjective for dialogue. It suggests that the sentences are short and witty; that the responses come quickly; that the conversation goes back and forth quickly.

*Whip-snap* simply emphasises that adjective; the conversation is snappy like a whip.

Comment: A very appropriate analogy.

Answer (score 2):

I can only suppose from the context that it means something like ‘fast and furious’. It calls to mind the term *whipper-snapper*, but that has a quite different meaning as an insignificant, but often impertinent, young man. According to the OED, Thackeray created  the adjective *whipping-snapping* from it and used it on a single occasion to mean ‘diminutive, insignificant’, but it is nowhere else recorded.

Answer (score 1):

Further ot @Slim - who is correct, and it relates to the snap of a whip - the term whip-snap, as opposed to just snappy, implies very quick and clever dialogue or responses. Full of clever one-liners, and a minimalist approach to dialogue.